# How do I use SQL like I use Python by duplicating rows while changing one value in that row where that value is derived from a different column?

Tags: python, sql, string, stored-procedures

I'm at an impasse (not being any better than a novice in SQL). I want to build a POC in SQL that will do something that I have already, very easily, done in Python. Here's the meat-

```
 TEXT |  PID   | PATCHES
------------------------------------------------------
'abc' | 123456 | '839264, 129361, 927301'
'def' | 234567 | '736492\n 928537'
'ghi' | 284554 | 'Text here #490238Text here #110299'
'jkl' | 776493 | '290389'
```

What I need is the following-

```
 TEXT |  PID
--------------
'abc' | 123456
'abc' | 839264
'abc' | 129361
'abc' | 927301
'def' | 234567
'def' | 736492
'def' | 928537
'ghi' | 284554
'ghi' | 490238
'ghi' | 110299
'jkl' | 776493
'jkl' | 290389
```

As you can see, I've copied the values in `TEXT` for each value that pops up in the `PATCHES` column while maintaining that the `PID` values are still in the new table.

In Python you can use `split()` and `find()` and append to a list, etc. but this is wayyy over my head right now.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! By the way, feel free to tell me that it's best done in Python and I will gladly forward that information to my team.

Comment: You can do it in SQL by using `substring()`,`stuff()`,`charindex()`  and few more functions to assist you in dynamic sql `stored procedure`.

Comment: Can you please post your answer or examples of how to use those for my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

1. Create A Temporary Table
2. Put all the values from main table to temporary table (With Identity(1,1))
3. Use a loop, upto the length of the 'temp' table
4. Pass every value/row into a stored procedure, and perform your operations.

   4.1 You can perform String_Split in SQL Server, by changing database comparability to 130.

   4.2 You can return result after performing operations.

Here, is sample demonstration:

```
Create Table #Temp
(
    Entity Int Identity(1,1),
    Text VarChar(3),
    Strings VarChar(100)
)
Insert #Temp
Select Text, Pid+ '-'+Patches From dbo.Errors

--Select * From dbo.#Temp;
Declare @Count As Int = (Select Count(*) From dbo.Errors)
Declare @i as Int = 1
While @i <= @Count
Begin
    Declare @Text As VarChar(3), @Strings As VarChar(100) 

    --select value one by one, and pass it into a stored procedure
    Select @Text = Text, @Strings = Strings From dbo.#Temp Where Entity = @i;
    Exec dbo.ErrorsProc @Text, @Strings

    Set @i = @i +1
End
```